# unclarity about proof for equivalent manifold definition from Shifrin

Tags: multivariable-calculus, manifolds

I'm reading through the book Linear Algebra, Multivariable Calculus and Manifolds by Theodore Shifrin and on page 262 he gives the following three equivalent criteria if a set $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a k-dimensional manifold

1. For any $p \in M$ there is a neighborhood $W \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ of p so that $M \cap W$ is the graph of a smooth function $f\colon V \mapsto \mathbb{R}^{n-k}$, where $V \subset \mathbb{R}^k$ is an open set. Here we are allowed to choose any $k$ integers $1\leq i_1 \dots i_k \leq n$; then $\mathbb{R}^k$ is the $x_{i_1}\dots x{i_k}$ plane and $\mathbb{R^{n-k}}$ is the plane of the complementary coordinates.
2. For any $p \in M$ there are a neighborhood $W \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ of $p$ and a smooth function $F\colon W \mapsto \mathbb{R}^{n-k}$ so that $F^{-1}(0)=M \cap W$ and $rank(DF(x))=n-k$ for every $x \in M \cap W$.
3. For any $p \in M$ there is a neighborhood $W \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ of $p$ so that $M \cap W$ is the image of a smooth function $g\colon U \mapsto \mathbb{R}^n$ for some open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^k$ with the properties that $g$ is one-to-one, $rank(Dg(u))=k$ for all $u \in U$, and $g^{-1}\colon M \cap W \mapsto U$ is continuous.

My question is about the proof for 1) implies 3) where it says that it's obvious because we can set $g(u) = \begin{pmatrix}u\\f(u)\end{pmatrix}$.

I can see why g satisfies all conditions except the continuity of $g^{-1}$, which I've been thinking about for some hours now but still don't have any idea how to prove.
Could someone explain me this part please ?

Thank you

Comment: First of all, why is $g$ invertible? Next, what is the inverse function of $g$?

Comment: @peek-a-boo g being injective and surjective between $U$ and $M \cap W$ is clear so there's no problem about the invertible part; I thought about what the inverse might be but I'm not sure how to go about it; probably I have to use the inverse function theorem or implicit function theorem somehow ?

Comment: No, not at all. There’s a very obvious inverse. If I give you a point on the graph, what’s the most obvious way to get back to the domain? How do you get back to the point on the graph?

Comment: @peek-a-boo oh, the inverse is just the projection on the first k coordinates, right ?

Comment: bingo, and isn’t that obviously continuous :)

Comment: @peek-a-boo it's so obvious I can't believe how much I was over complicating things :) Thanks for you comments, it pushed me to the correct conclusion

Comment: @tedshifrin is that your book? then maybe you could help OP...